# When should I use With-End With and when should I use normal object references in VB6?

Tags: optimization, syntax, vb6

Perusing the code I am maintaining, I see that in some places the `With - End With` construct is used...

```
With my_object
    .do_this()
    .do_that()
    .do_the_other()
End With
```

and sometimes the more straightforward

```
my_object.do_this()
my_object.do_that()
my_object.do_the_other()
```

Are there any subtle differences between these two forms? And in general, which should I prefer?

(My personal view is that I go for the second because after two or three nestings for the first it starts to make my head hurt - is that an adequate reason?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin is incorrect.  `With...End With` construct is not just syntactic candy, it's also a performance trick. When you have an object path that includes several dots (.), the performance increase is pretty noticeable, particularly when looping and/or dealing with `Types` (structs).

For instance, this code:

```
For x = 1 to my_object.Employee.Records.Count
    Debug.Print my_object.Employee.Records(x).ID
Next
```

will be much faster as:

```
For x = 1 to my_object.Employee.Records.Count
    With my_object.Employee.Records(x)
        Debug.Print .ID
    End With
Next
```

and, as pointed out by @wqw, it will likely be even faster (depending on how many properties you need to access) like this since it offers the least amount of object re-qualification:

```
With my_object.Employee.Records
    For x = 1 to .Count
        Debug.Print Item(x).ID
    Next    
End With
```

Give it a shot, you'll see the difference.

Comment: More like `With my_object.Employee.Records` outsite the loop and then `Debug.Print .Item(x).ID` inside

Comment: Are you saying the first or second one will be faster?  (Sorry, I'm just not sure whether "much faster as" means "much faster than" or "much faster if changed to").  If the second one is faster, that is indeed interesting -- do you know why it's faster?

Comment: @Justin, the second one is **much** faster.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference if the object reference is actually a more complicated expression, like a property getter or the return value of a function.

Compare this:

```
With MyObjectFactory.CreateMyObject()
    .do_this
    .do_that
    .WriteToDatabase
End With
```

Against the obviously incorrect:

```
MyObjectFactory.CreateMyObject().do_this
MyObjectFactory.CreateMyObject().do_that
MyObjectFactory.CreateMyObject().WriteToDatabase
```

The actual equivalent in this case would be to create a reference:

```
Dim myObject as MyObject
Set myObject = MyObjectFactory.CreateMyObject() 
myObject.do_this
myObject.do_that
myObject.WriteToDatabase
```

As to whether you should use With blocks, it is really a matter of personal preference.  Like you, I would certainly find many nested With blocks confusing.  It is probably also a sign that the function should be split into multiple functions.

Comment: I don't buy the "nesting is bad" argument.  You might as easily claim that nesting If-blocks is a sign you should split the procedure.  Ridiculous.  The cached anonymous reference doesn't cost you anything either, while declaring another reference variable counts against your module and Project symbol totals.  It's more a question of how well you understand the language, and newbs will prefer hyperqualification of each use of an object.

Comment: @Bob - Personally, I would get confused with many nested With blocks (more than 2 or 3, like the OP said).  Same thing with nested if statements -- it starts to get confusing and difficult to refactor once they are nested too deep.

Comment: @Bob - Good to know that reference variables count against the symbol totals -- I never even thought about there being a limit.  A quick search shows it to be about 32k symbols ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240819%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)).

Comment: Well there's no question deep indentation becomes a problem before too long.  Doesn't matter which block structures you nest: Ifs, Select Cases, Withs, Fors, etc.

Comment: Justin, the primary purpose of using With..End With is to only do object requalification once and thus increase performance.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

New answer just to post code.

Note that object caching doesn't always do what you expect whether using the anonymous With-cache or an explicit reference variable (or procedure argument).  Both DumpRS and DumpRSII below do the same thing, printing all of the values in RS:

```
Option Explicit
'Add a reference to ADO 2.5 or later.

Private RS As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub MakeRS()
    Dim I As Integer

    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    With RS
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Fields.Append "SomeField", adInteger
        .Open
        For I = 1 To 10
            .AddNew Array(0), Array(I)
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DumpRS()
    With RS.Fields(0)
        RS.MoveFirst
        Do Until RS.EOF
            Debug.Print .Value
            RS.MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub DumpRSII(ByVal Field As ADODB.Field)
    With RS
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            Debug.Print Field.Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Main()
    MakeRS
    DumpRS
    DumpRSII RS.Fields(0)
    RS.Close
End Sub
```

The Field object is just a window on the cursor.  Caching Field objects can improve the performance of repeated-by-row ADO operations significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the first version only for setting property values like an initialization block in C#.  If you are calling methods etc., then use the second form.